# unable to display Euro symbol in reports page

Tags: visualforce

I'm having little trouble on displaying some currencies in reports. refer my code

```
<apex:page contentType="application/vnd.ms-excel#contacts.xls">
<table>
<tr>

<td><apex:outputText value="$"></apex:outputText></td>
<td><apex:outputText value="€"></apex:outputText></td>
<td><apex:outputText value="£"></apex:outputText></td>
<td><apex:outputText value="C$"></apex:outputText></td>
<td><apex:outputText value="HK$"></apex:outputText></td>
</tr>
</table>
</apex:page>
```

here, is the output:

```
$   â‚¬ Â£  C$  HK$
```

Any ideas on how to to fix them

Comment: Try the following and see if it works. `<apex:outputText value="&euro;" escape="false"></apex:outputText>`

Comment: Thank you. It's working. Also, i got another solution also. It's by including below header tag, we can fix it: 
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
</head>